# Autodesk Viewer Shows Black Model

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

When using the Autodesk Viewer in different browsers, sometimes models do not display with textures and instead show black. This has been encountered in Chrome on Ubuntu 16.04, as well as Safari on iOS 10.3.3.

What causes this? If this isn't known, how can we begin to debug this?

---

[image: incorrect display]

[image: incorrect display]

Comment: The version of the browser is not supporting the shaders that are used by the viewer, not much you can do about it on your side, this would need to be fixed in the viewer code...

Comment: Can we get some indication as to when this will be fixed?

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the same issue in safari on iOS https://imgur.com/gallery/SexoA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found an undocumented updated to the viewer - version v2.16. We have updated to use this version and the models are now rendering correctly.